# Change font color upon hover

Tags: html, css, hover

basically, what I would like this code to do is whenever you hover over the button, the background will turn blue, and the text's color will turn white. I have tried:

```
.btn1:hover a{
  background:#fff;
}
```

but this did not work.

```
<div class="container">
   <a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">HTML</button></a>
<a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">C/C++</button></a>
<a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">JavaScript</button></a>
<a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">CSS</button></a></div>

.container{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:200px;
}

.btn {
  border:1px solid #3498db;
  background:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:10px;
  transition:0.8s;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.btn1 {
  color:#3498db;
}

.btn1:hover{
  background:#3498db;
}
```

Comment: Please run your code through a validator. It is illegal HTML - "The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also set the text color to white on hover:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn1 {
  color: #3498db;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">HTML</button></a>
  <a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">C/C++</button></a>
  <a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">JavaScript</button></a>
  <a href="#"> <button class="btn btn1">CSS</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the small error you are doing is you are trying to change the color of
 which is outside of 
instead try changing the font of the button which is made so i think:

```
.btn1:hover{
  background-color:blue; //choose your blue color
  color: white; // this defin the font color
}
```

sorry if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

You were just missing the color white in the last class for the hover effect with CSS:

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:200px;
}

.btn {
  border:1px solid #3498db;
  background:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:10px;
  transition:0.8s;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.btn1 {
  color:#3498db;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background:#3498db;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="container">enter code here
  <a href="#"><button class="btn btn1">HTML</button></a>
  <a href="#"><button class="btn btn1">C/C++</button></a>
  <a href="#"><button class="btn btn1">JavaScript</button></a>
  <a href="#"><button class="btn btn1">CSS</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).